# Is there a way to check from within a Java class that it's super class is of the same type?

Tags: java, inheritance, decorator, subclass, superclass

I am instantiating a decorator variable and I need a way to check if it is a decorator within another decorator of the same type.

For example

```
Object o = new Decorator(new Decorator(new Enemy("Enemy1")));
System.out.println(o.getName());
```

What I am currently trying to do is this within **Decorator.java**

```
public String getName()
{
    return "Decorator " + super.getName();
}
```

Outputting

```
Decorator Decorator Enemy1
```

So I am trying to solve the Decorator being displayed twice by

```
public String getName()
{
    if (super instanceof Decorator)
    {
        return super.getName();
    }
    return "Decorator " + super.getName();
}
```

But that isn't the correct use of super and it throws an error so I was wondering what a better approach would be

Comment: Why aren't you delegating to the decorated value? What is `super.getName()` calling?

Comment: When calling `new Decorator(new Decorator(new Enemy())` you are not putting `Enemy` into a super class relationship with `Decorator`. Rather you compose a `Decorator` from a `Enemy`.

Comment: This very much looks like you're using the decorator pattern wrong. Either way, it's not the responsibility of the decorator to check what it's decorating, but of the class doing the decorating to check what decorators to apply.